# OnTimer never being called, unsure why?

Tags: c++, timer, mfc, dialog

Having some trouble here, right now I'm just trying to make an image move across the screen, the variables and positioning is working but for some reason the OnTimer is never called, I put a breakpoint inside it and it was never reached. No errors so I presume all methods and variables are defined correctly in the header.

Thanks in advance

```
BOOL Client::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    //StartGame();

    m_PlayerPosTop = 0;  // 384
    m_PlayerPosLeft = 0;
    m_PlayerImg.MoveWindow(m_PlayerPosLeft, m_PlayerPosTop, 16, 16);
    m_nTimer = SetTimer(0, 1000, 0);

    return TRUE;
}

    void Client::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{

    m_PlayerPosLeft++;
    m_PlayerImg.MoveWindow(m_PlayerPosLeft, m_PlayerPosTop, 16, 16);

    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MFC is a *message-driven* system, one possible reason that you don't see your `OnTimer` fired is because you forgot to locate `ON_WM_TIMER()` in the right place.

```
BEGIN_MEESAGE_MAP(...)
     // ..
     ON_WM_TIMER()
     // ..
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something simple! Thank you very much.